# <a href="Music/bonapart.html">...</a> works fine but <a href="/Music/bonapart.html">...</a> gives error

Tags: html, hyperlink, path

**Code-1**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>Relative Link</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                child folder <a href="Music/17_2.html">17_2</a>
            </p>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Output

```
child folder 17_2
```

**Code-2**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Relative Link</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            
            child folder <a href="/Music/17_2.html">17_2</a>
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

What's the significance of extra forward slash `/` At beginning of path entered in the value of attribute `href`

Comment: @Ivar No. In the answer he mention when we start `/` forward slash it is absolute path it read from root of site. But why then it not finding my file ?

Comment: Because your file is not at `/Music/17_2.html` from the root of your the site. (i.e. if you go to `http://example.com/Music/17_2.html`, your file will not be there.)

Comment: See it contains in my folder and I am making webpage with .html in notepad it is not hosted anywhere. how it can start with `http` ? I don't know exactly what is
happening I am new to html.

Comment: If you are running it locally without any webserver, then `/` will point to the root of your directory tree. So if you have your file on `file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.html`, then `href="/Music/17_2.html"` will take you to `file:///C:/Music/17_2.html`. If you want it to work with an absolute path, you need to provide the full path from the root of your drive.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand concept and also understand  Q. you referred and answer to that. yes my Q. is duplicate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resolving relative URLs you first determine the base URL.

For a link in an HTML document, that is the URL of the HTML document (unless overridden with a `<base>` element).

e.g. `http://example.com/foo/bar` contains your link.

### Relative paths

Then if the URL is a **relative path** (i.e. is a path that does not start with a `/`):

1. Any query string and fragment identifier is removed from the base URL
2. Everything after the **last `/`** in the base URL is removed.
3. The path is appended

`http://example.com/foo/bar` + `baz` = `http://example.com/foo/baz`

### Absolute paths

If the URL is an **absolute path** (i.e. starts with a single `/`) then:

1. Any query string and fragment identifier is removed from the base URL
2. The existing path (i.e. everything after the **authority** (hostname+port number)) is removed (note that you don't often see port numbers in URLs outside of development environments)
3. The path is appended

`http://example.com/foo/bar` + `/baz` = `http://example.com/baz`

---

Do not confuse an absolute **path** with an absolute **url** (the later of which starts with the scheme such as `https://`).

There is a useful diagram of the parts of a URL in section 3 of the [URL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3)

Comment: fist of all thanks. Mostly I got all. How to determine  Base URL and is it  different for absolute path and relative path ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane — Umm. See the second paragraph of this answer. It's the first thing I said after saying you needed to determine the base URL.

Comment: I am not getting clearly that point. `http://example.com/foo/baz` it containing link we want to refer from html document which is present in `http://example.com/foo` right ? please elaborate and  I am not hosting website on webserver just I am doing all this in file and notepad with .html extension. But I can understand.

Comment: You type `http://example.com/foo/baz` into the address bar in your browser. That gives you a web page. It is the base URL for links in that webpage. The web page is built around an HTML document. That HTML document contains a link. That link has `href="baz"` or `href="/baz"`. You navigate to the page at the URLs described in this answer.

Comment: Base URL is same no matter we choose absolute path or relative path. It is basically path up-to  current directory right ?

Comment: please do reply. What's difference between absolute URL and absolute path ?

Comment: `http://example.com/foo/bar` is an absolute URL; `/foo/bar` is an absolute path

Comment: @ Quentin is my 2nd last comment is right ?