# why differences there in .html file on local host and .html file uploaded on web?

Tags: html, image, web-hosting, case-sensitive

**index.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <p> 
            <img src="kRIsten stewart.jpg" width="200"  height="200"  alt="Kristen stewart" title="Kristen stewart" />
            <img src="pics/Emilia clarke.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="emilia clarke" title="emilia clarke" />
            <img src="jordan-peterson.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="jorden-peterson" title="jorden-peterson" />
            <img src="pics/Kate winslet.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="kate winslet" title="kate winslet" />
            <img src="/4. Codes/HTML/hosted2/Mel robbins.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="Mel robbins" title="Mel robbins"/>
            <img src="raining gif.gif" height="200" width="200" alt="raining gif" title="raining gif" />

            
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Location : `F:/4. codes/html/hosted2/`

This `hosted2` folder is hosted on `surge.sh` . It contains `index.html` file, `jorden-peterson.jpg`, `kristen stewart.jpg`, `Mel robbins.jpg`, `raining.gif`. It also contains a folder named `pics`, which contains `Emilia clarke.jpg`, and `kate winslet.jpg`.

When I open this `index.html` using file scheme `file:/// F:/...`, all 6 pics display in the web-browser.

But when I open this file through URL `http://unsuitable-rate_bonapart.surge.sh/` where it is hosted, I am unable to see `kristen stewart.jpg` and `Mel robbins.jpg`. Why is that ?

1.kristen stewart.jpg.

I make 2 letters uppercase while giving path in index.html file KRIsten stewart.jpg. But in location the file is kristen stewart.jpg

5.Mel robbins.jpg

/4. Codes/HTML/hosted2/Mel robbins.jpg I gave absolute path.

So what I feel that on browser while uploading I uploaded `hosted2` folder so it doesn't know upper folders to that(hosted2) so It can't show `Mel robbins.jpg` and `kristen stewart.jpg`. I feel it's due to surge.sh might have policy that the file name should be case sensitive.

So I feel this. I don't know exactly. Please explain why this is happening.

Comment: The webserver and/or the OS the webserver is running on decide if the filenames are case sensitive or not. On linux systems, the name is case sensitive, on windows system (like your PC) the name is case-insensive. So on **your** PC it works fine, but on a deployed server with case-sensitive names, the filename "kRIsten stewart.jpg" is different than "kristen stewart.jpg". In fact, http://unsuitable-rate_bonapart.surge.sh/kristen%20stewart.jpg works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use spaces in your img src (replace them by "-" or "_").

If your kristen stewart's file name is kristen-stewart.jpg then call it by kristen-stewart.jpg not kRIsten-stewart.jpg.

Then /4. Codes/HTML/hosted2/Mel robbins.jpg is not an absolute path. An absolute path will be (for example) https://yourdomainname.com/yourimage.jpg. So maybe consider relative path or a valide absolute path.

Note: Add "./" at the beginning of your src to use the same folder and "../" to move to the upper folder.

Comment: `then call it by kristen-stewart.jpg not kRIsten-stewart.jpg.`  My Q is why then it is running for file:///

Comment: `"./" at the beginning of your src`  move to root directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453187/11862989 check this for it is absolute path or not ?