# When I upload image on website by changing pixels by using attributes width and height but when I download it again. It have original dimensions only

Tags: html, pixel

kristen_stewart.jpg dimensions: 400 x 270

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <p> 
            <img src="pics/kristen_stewart.jpg" width="200"  height="200"  alt="Kristen stewart" title="Kristen stewart" />
            
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

So when I am uploading it I alters the dimensions to 200 x 200 but when I download it from webpage it still containing dimensions 400 x 270. So why is this happening ?

Comment: The attributes `width=""` and `height=""` do not edit the loaded image in any way, it just change how big the image will be displayed (and automatically scaled up/down by the browser). What exactly is the problem you have and what are you trying to do?

Comment: _"So why is this happening ?"_ Why *wouldn't* it happen?

Comment: @Progman I just download the image which I put on web by changing dimension then I see it's dimensions are original one not which on web-browser so I feel that strange . so I asked it. By the way I got it. Thanks

Comment: @j08691 I got it via comment of  `program`. Thanks

Comment: @Progman https://stackoverflow.com/q/68479584/11862989 can you answer this Question please.

Comment: @j08691 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68479584/11862989 can you answer this Question please.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS in the `img` tag displays the image in the dimensions `200 x 200`, it doesn't affect the dimensions of image file in any way

If you want to allow the user to crop the image file before uploading, you would've to use some JavaScript library like [Cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md)